# Mudar nome de arq com upload multiplo

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tenho um formulario que contem um input do tipo file, onde eu preciso enviar varios arq ao mesmo tempo:

```
<div class="row p-3 hours_week" *ngFor="let subType of finalResultTotal">

      <input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" multiple id="{{subType}}SlotsInput"
                  [name]="subType.DATA_DIA+uploadHtml" class="text-light" (change)="inputFileChange($event)" multiple
                  ngModel #inpt="ngModel" #inpt="ngModel">
</div>
```

no ts eu faço assim:

```
  public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({
    isHTML5: true
  });
```

...

```
  constructor(){}

...

    onSubmit(form) {

          for (var j = 0; j < this.uploader.queue.length; j++) {
              this.enviaFoto = new FormData();

              this.fileItem = this.uploader.queue[j]._file;

       this.enviaFoto.append('photo', this.fileItem, this.fileItem.name);
      this.enviaFoto.append('fileSeq', 'seq' + j);
      this.uploadFile(this.enviaFoto).subscribe(data => 
           }
    this.uploader.clearQueue();
    }


  uploadFile(data: FormData): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:3000/novaphoto', data);
  }
```

Os arq sao inseridos na minha api tudo de boa, mas aí eu preciso mudar o nome dos arq antes de enviar, e fiz o seguindo:

onSubmit(form) {

```
  for (var j = 0; j < this.uploader.queue.length; j++) {
      this.enviaFoto = new FormData();

      this.fileItem = this.uploader.queue[j]._file;


    if (this.day3.DIA === this.finalResultTotal[0].DATA_DIA) {
      this.day3.HORA = this.finalResultTotal[0].HORAS
      this.day3.SOBRA = this.finalResultTotal[0].TOTAL

      this.Day1Final = this.day3


    } else {

    }

    if (this.day3.DIA === this.finalResultTotal[1].DATA_DIA) {
      this.day3.HORA = this.finalResultTotal[1].HORAS
      this.day3.SOBRA = this.finalResultTotal[1].TOTAL

      this.Day2Final = this.day3

    } else {

    }
```

...

```
 if (this.Day1Final.UPLOAD) {

      Object.defineProperty(this.fileItem, 'name', {
        writable: true,
        value: (this.Day1Final.DIA).trim()
      });
      this.enviaFoto.append('photo', this.fileItem, this.fileItem.name);
      this.enviaFoto.append('fileSeq', 'seq' + j);
      this.uploadFile(this.enviaFoto).subscribe(data => console.log(data.message));
    }

    if (this.Day2Final.UPLOAD) {
      let foto = new FormData()
      Object.defineProperty(this.fileItem, 'name', {
        writable: true,
        value: (this.Day2Final.DIA).trim()
      });
      foto.append('photo', this.fileItem, this.fileItem.name);
      foto.append('fileSeq', 'seq' + j);
      this.uploadFile(foto).subscribe(data => console.log(data.message));

    }

       }
this.uploader.clearQueue();
}
```

Caso o this.Day1Final.UPLOAD seja true, quer dizer que tem algum arquivo nesse array, assim como o Day2Final.

Envio para a api e é enviada com sucesso, nome do jeito que eu quero, mas nao vai as fotos diferentes, ele ta enviando a mesma foto só que com nomes diferentes.

Poderiam me ajudar?